# Django QuerySet: Figure Out Model Attribute Trend Between 5 Returned

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

```
notifications = DeviceNotification.objects.all()

    for n in notifications:

        time_period = n.time_period

        logs = DeviceLog.objects.all()[:time_period]

        for l in logs:

            print(l.celsius)
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I would discover the temperature "trend" or "spread" between the object attributes (lets use celsius) returned.

Basically, I want to be able to tell if the temperature has risen by a certain amount, or dropped by a certain amount... for example: `if celsius has increased by 2 degrees within the past 5 hours`

I'm not sure if this can be done by way of a filter or if I'll have to add each `celsius` value to an array and compare the array with `abs()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by keeping logs of temperature against time period.

Let's say you have temperature log and you wants to find if temperature has increased in past 5 hours,

You can get temperature value of now and before 5 hours

```
log_now = TemperatureLog.objects.get(created=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=1))

log_past = TemperatureLog.objects.get(created=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=5))
```

Now, you can do like this,

if (log_now.celsius - log_past.celsius) > 1:
    return "temperature increased by 2 Celsius"
else:
    return "temperature not increased by 2 Celsius"

Comment: And that is exactly what im doing. Every hour, the temperature is recorded. So, depending on the time period selected, I need to be able to see what the trend is.

Comment: I change `get` to `filter`, but I'm getting: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'celsius'`

Comment: Can you please show me your models?, so that I can guide you by actual field names.

Answer (score 0):

Follow your model:

```
notifications = DeviceNotification.objects.all()

for n in notifications:

    time_period = n.time_period

    logs = DeviceLog.objects.all()[:time_period]

    for l in logs:

        print(l.celsius)
```

I change it to:

```
logs = DeviceLog.objects.all()          

log_now = logs[datetime.datetime.now()].celsius
log_pre = logs[datetime.datetime.now() - 5].celsius
dif = log_now - log_pre         
if (dif) >=0:
    print ("increased: ",dif,"in 5 hours")
else:
    print ("decreased: ",dif,"in 5 hours")
```